# Pending developer action for OAuth consent screen

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-oauth

I submitted a Web application for OAuth consent screen. I have been waiting for two weeks.

In the OAuth consent screen I see this problem :
[image]

The domain is verified in Google Webmaster Console.

I didn't receive any email from Google Trust and Safety team. So, how I can contact them?

Thank you in advance for your help.

Comment: Have you checked your email they probably sent you an email already telling you what the issue is.

Comment: Yes, a checked the two email addresses given but I didn't receive any issue from Google.

Answer (score 1):

The message states

> Ensure that your application domains have completed the search console verification process

Any domain that you have added you need to prove that you own.

> Verification is the process of proving that you own the property that you claim to own. Search Console needs to verify ownership because verified owners have access to sensitive Google Search data for a site, and can affect a site's presence and behavior on Google Search and other Google properties. A verified owner can grant full or view access to other people.

You should read though [Verify your site ownership](https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/9008080?hl=en)

Comment: Thank you for your reply. 
There is only one domain. This domaine is already validated in Google Console.
The owner in Google Console is the same in Google Cloud.

Comment: This is the error message they are giving you.   One of the domains you are using is not verified to you.   check your redirect uri's, check the domains where you are hosting for example your home page or the privacy policy.  One if them is not registered to you.

Comment: I checked:

* Application home page
* Application privacy link
* Application Terms of Service link
* Authorised domains
* Authorised JavaScript origins
* Authorised redirect URIs

There is one domain and a subdomain who belongs to the same owner in Google Cloud + Google Console.

Comment: You will need to find the email that google sent you and ask them for more information.   This is the error message they are giving you the domain hasn't "completed the search console verification"  There for your only option is to contact them asking which domain or check yourself until you find out which domain has not been though search console verification.

Answer (score 1):

I finally found the email from Google Cloud in my spam box. Sorry for this issue.